# What is the difference between 总是 and 一直?

Tags: preposition, difference

I've always (no pun intended) wondered what the difference is between the two words. I thought they both meant always, but I've never quite grasped in what context they should be used.

Could anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are synonyms.

总是 places an emphasis on frequency.

> 他上课总是迟到 = He kept being late for class all the time.

一直 places an emphasis on consistency.

> 他一直是个好孩子 = He has been a good kid through the years.

Comment: Great, thanks for this. So the 2nd form could perhaps be remembered as being used in more long-term expressions?

Comment: @jaffa I think both are being used in equally long-term expressions.

Comment: @jaffa: I think the point is that 总是 means "frequently" in the sense of many frequent discrete events, whereas 一直 means "continually" in the sense of something happening continuously over a span of time.  As Terry says, they are synonyms, but they transmit different feelings.

Answer (score 2):

总是 means "every time."

一直 means "continuously."

The first is "discrete." The second is "continuous." But they both mean "always."